# Ubuntu 18.04 - Battery draining while laptop powered down

Tags: 18.04, power-management, laptop, battery

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Precision 5520 laptop with a Microsoft wireless keyboard 3050 and wireless mouse 5000. Before upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04, I could power down at the end of the day and come back the next day to find a fully charged battery. After upgrading, I would power down at the end of the day and find that my battery was below 90% when I returned to work the next day. Last night, I unplugged the USB wireless receiver after I powered down the laptop. This morning, the laptop's battery was fully charged when I turned on the computer. So, it seems that the wireless receiver continues to draw power even after the computer is off.

This issue may also be related to the erratic behavior of the mouse cursor on startup. When I leave the wireless receiver plugged in over night, the mouse has significant skipping and lag behaviors on startup the next day.

Why is the wireless receiver drawing power in 18.04, when it didn't in 16.04? And what can I do to prevent that behavior, other than unplugging the receiver every time I power down the laptop?

Comment: Strange, never heard something like that. Do you have a small lightning on your USB port where the receiver was connected on? Can you try another port?

Comment: No, there isn't a lightning emblem. It's just a USB port. I can try the port where my external hard drive is connected, but it's identical.

Comment: Since this keyboard has, at best, "limited functionality" with anything other than Windows, every update could be an adventure. You probably just need to raise this as a defect with Canonical. My guess is that nothing special was done for support in Linux and it just sort of worked good enough, but some changes uncovered the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to raise the issue with Canonical. In truth, I've found the keyboard's functionality to be quite good.